@Role in IntegrationFlow DSL
Is it possible to specify the endpoint role used for leadership election through the IntegrationFlow dsl when using a message driven channel adapter?
I can create a JMS message driven endpoint using the Jms dsl and set the role on the endpoint but I can't see a method to specify the role through the IntegrationFlow dsl.

The MessageProducerSpec, a super class of the JmsMessageDrivenChannelAdapterSpec is rally missing that property now.
Will be fixed soon. The release is next week.
Meanwhile you can do something like this:
JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint jmsMessageDrivenEndpoint = 
                Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(amqFactory)
                        .destination("some_destination")
                        .getObject();
        jmsMessageDrivenEndpoint.setRole("some_role");

        return IntegrationFlow
                .from(jmsMessageDrivenEndpoint)

